# How to check if value isset then echo value property [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I have input with name of "username" and what I need is when I send the form to check whether the value was sent with the form I want to print the property inside input as:

```
<input type="text" name="username"
 <?php if(isset($uname)){echo 'value="' . $uname . '"';} ?>
>
```

So I don't want to print value property unless there's a value already sent by POST method.

The code I have for now is:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"
 value="<?php if(isset($uname)){echo $uname;}?>"
 placeholder="Username">
```

It's working fine but its printing value property even before I send the form, I have tried to modify the code, but the closing tag of input [ > ] seems to have problem with php closing tag ?>

**How I can solve this issue?**

Thanks a lot :)

---

Thanks, I solved it like this:

```
<?php
  echo '<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"';
  echo (isset($uname)) ? 'value="'.$uname.'"' : '';
  echo ' placeholder="Username">';
?>
```

Note: 
I already had declared $uname = $_POST['username']; in another place, so that's why I have a valid variable ($uname).

Comment: Don't you just need to replace `$uname` with `$_POST['uname']` (both in the isset function and in the echo)?

Comment: I have a variable called $uname  = $_POST['username']; so there's no need to write the post variable in its classic way because I already have the variable declared ..

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit the question title.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin, out of curiosity, could you show example of successfull XSS in this case?

Comment: `<form method="post" action="your url"><input type="hidden" name="username" value='  "><script>alert("xss")</script>   '></form><script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>` (untested, off the top of my head)

Comment: If your variable $uname is already declared then isset($uname) will always return true :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the post variables (which you don't show here)

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['uname']): ?>
   value="<?php echo $_POST['uname'];?>"
<?php endif; ?>
```

Change the contente of post by what you have and it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already know this solution. But what I need is to no print (echo) the property (value="..") unless there's a value is set by the form (send by using POST).. I don't want (value="") markup to be along with the other properties (name, id, etc..) Hope this clarify my question..

Comment: have you tried the solution i gave you ? it's easier to read than all those echo you v done in your edit

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo (isset($uname) && isset($_POST['uname'])) ? $uname : '';?>" placeholder="Username">
```

Don't forget to use **filter_input**(http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) on your $uname variable before using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already know this solution. But what I need is to no print (echo) the property (value="..") unless there's a value is set by the form (send by using POST)..

I don't want (value="") markup to be along with the other properties (name, id, etc..)

Hope this clarify my question..